# Windows forms resets to default value

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

question i am going to ask may might be a silly question. i have tried a lot but i could not be able to figure out what happens my form. therefore please help me.

basically what i need to do is i need to re size my window size according to a given dimension

my code goes as below

```
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.Text = "";
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Icon = null;
        this.Size = new Size(10, 10); // my size 
        this.MaximumSize = new Size(10, 10); // my size
```

but when the form loads dimensions has been changed to (132,10)

suggestions please

Comment: Have you tried to set those configurations on the `Form1_Load?`

Comment: And is the constructor actually being called?

Comment: @Ghaleon Doing it in `Load` still doesn't guarantee it won't be resized...better to do it in `Shown` or at least `Layout`.

Comment: @Ghaleon yes i did :(

Comment: @MikeCheel yes : i dont have any other methods

Comment: The code works for me. My guess is either the constructor is not being called. I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: if you can give me your mail id i can send you my sample app :) or else please send your to me sumudu.ks@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the resizing code into a `Shown` event handler:

```
private void myForm_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Size = new Size(10, 10); // my size 
    this.MaximumSize = new Size(10, 10); // my size
}
```

You can add this handler in the form designer under properties, and using the events list.

Read more:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984320(v=vs.71).aspx

PS:  as another poster (N4TKD) suggested, the `AutoSize` property should be set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You should set AutoSize to false, the size is most likely to small for the control that are added to it.

Comment: @n4tkd : i did that as well but no luck :(

Comment: try             this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;

Comment: and make sure MaximizeBox is set to false.

Comment: @N4TKD : thanks for your comment highly appreciated. i have tried above two options which you are suggesting but didnt work

Comment: OK one more thing you are setting the MaximumSize what is the MinimumSize set to? try setting it to 0, 0 or at least 9, 9.

Comment: @Prabhakantha what do you mean by `didn't work`, how is the actual size? I think `AutoSize=false` will allow you to set the form `Size` freely, your code is placed in the right place, don't need to move it to a Form Load event handler.

Comment: I edited you answer this my codes looks likes now :) after doing the suggestions :)